What is the solution set to $ \cos(8x) = - \frac{ 1 }{ 6 } $?
This was a question on Khan Academy that Sal Khan works through here.
I'm really sorry if this isn't clear. I've included a hand-drawn diagram nearer the bottom to help clarify my thinking if any of this is confusing.
This was my solution:
$ \begin{aligned} x \ &= \ ± \left( \frac{ \arccos\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right) }{ 8 } + \frac{ \pi n }{ 4 } \right) \\ \text{or} \\ x \ &= \ ± \left( \frac{ 2\pi - \arccos\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right) }{ 8 } + \frac{ \pi n }{ 4 } \right) \end{aligned} $
But the solution set given on Khan Academy was as follows:
$ \begin{aligned} x \ &= \ ± \left( \frac{ \arccos\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right) }{ 8 } - \frac{ \pi n }{ 4 } \right) \end{aligned} $
The way I understand the difference between my answer and KA's answer is that I figured there were essentially four parts to the solution set whereas KA seem to have focused on two. I don't know if my understanding is correct on that, though.
My reasoning is that the solution set for a cosine equation like this has four cases, because for any given value of $ \cos \theta $ there are two distinct points on the unit circle (these points being reflections of each other about the $x$-axis). Algebraically this is because cosine is an even function such that $ \cos(\theta) = \cos(-\theta) $. Attached to these two points are two radii that are likewise reflections of each other over the $x$-axis (see diagram). From the starting position of $ (0,1) $ on the unit circle, you can get to any one of those two points in two ways: clockwise (i.e. a negative angle $\theta$) or anticlockwise (i.e. a positive angle $\theta$).
My thought is that since any $\cos(8x)$ gives you two points on the unit circle, and there are two ways of getting to each of those points, surely there should be four parts to any given solution set for a cosine function.
As far as I can see, Sal Khan only solved for two out of the four cases:
$ \begin{aligned} \\ 8x &= \arccos\left(-\frac{ 1 }{ 6 }\right) + 2\pi n \\ \text{and} \\ 8x &= -\arccos\left(-\frac{ 1 }{ 6 }\right) - 2\pi n \end{aligned} $
Should he not have solved for these two cases as well:
$ \begin{aligned} 8x &= 2\pi - \arccos\left(-\frac{ 1 }{ 6 }\right) + 2\pi n \\ \text{and} \\ 8x &= - 2\pi + \arccos\left(-\frac{ 1 }{ 6 }\right) - 2\pi n \end{aligned} $
I drew a unit circle diagram (with pretty colours!) of what I mean. Looking at the diagram, if we consider only one full rotation in either direction around the unit circle, that gives us four different angles of size $8x$ (each in different colours, with their corresponding expressions) that satisfy $ \cos(8x) = - \frac{ 1 }{ 6 } $ (if we're only looking at one full rotation in either direction). So surely you'd just take these four solutions and tack $ + 2\pi n $ onto the positive angles and tack $ - 2\pi n $ onto the negative solutions, no?
My question is: Have I screwed up? And if so, how? Why is KA's answer correct and mine incorrect? Is my solution correct and just expressed differently (and I can't see it)?
I'm sorry. Despite my best efforts, I feel like none of the above makes a blind bit of sense.
If any kind person sees where I've erred and has a moment to explain, I'd be immensely grateful.

Look at the actual, explicit values that your solution set and theirs generate. Are they equal? If yes, why? If no, does the extraneous value satisfy the condition?

$2 \pi - \arccos(-1/6) + 2 \pi n = -\arccos(-1/6) + 2 \pi (n+1)$, so your extra two cases are already covered by the first two cases.

Don't really have a contribution, but nice diagram! :-)

@NaitikMundra ahh that's very kind, thank you! :)

As noticed in the comments, note that
$$x = \ ± \left( \frac{ 2\pi - \arccos\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right) }{ 8 } + \frac{ \pi n }{ 4 } \right)= \ ± \left( \frac{ - \arccos\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right) }{ 8 } + \frac{ \pi  }{ 4 }(n+1) \right)=\mp \left( \frac{  \arccos\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right) }{ 8 } - \frac{ N\pi  }{ 4 } \right)$$
with $N=n+1$, which is equivalent to the solution given by the academy.

Ooohhhhh. I think I forgot to consider that $n$ can be positive or negative, so you you don't need separate cases for subtracting $n$ because that will just happen when $n$ is negative. Is that right?

@TomMarshall Yes we have that $n \in \mathbb Z$.
